# Tile one polygon by anothers

Tags: algorithm, geometry, computational-geometry

Given are polygon defined by set of points (X, Y) with free points and another polygon inside it.

[image: picture 1]

I need to tile the initial polygon by another so that they don't cross and touch internal initial polygon and all free points should be inside them. Also there should be distance between received polygons, which concluded between given values. Resulted polygons should have no more than six angles.

[image: picture 2]

Are there any known algorithms to compute this?

Practical example of required result:

[image: picture 3]

Points:

[image]

Comment: According to your second picture there is some additional requirement that all the tiles should be not too large. Is it true? If yes, please express this requirement more formally and edit your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of ways to do this. Here is one:

Use any triangulation algorithm to triangulate the polygon (under consideration of the hole). Repeatedly pick adjacent triangles to form groups with at most six outer vertices. Shrink the groups and assert that the free points do not fall outside of a group.